# New to C... struct can't find a variable I identified

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to this whole C thing, but I keep getting this error with my code

```
UArray2.c:19:error: request for member ‘i’ in something not a structure or union
```

It's obviously the uarray.i in my main function, but I don't get why it isn't seeing it.

This is my .h file. Not too interesting...

```
//UArray2.h
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef UARRAY2_INCLUDED
#define UARRAY2_INCLUDED
#define T UArray2_T
typedef struct T *T;

#undef T
//#undef UARRAY2_INCLUDED //undef?                 
#endif
```

This is my .c file. Pretty simple stuff.

```
//UArray.c                                              
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "UArray2.h"
#define T UArray2_T

struct T{
     int i;
};

int main()
{
     UArray2_T uarray;
     uarray.i=0;
     return 0;
}
#undef T
```

So, does anyone have any idea as to why I'm getting this compile error? It's likely something stupid that I did.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't abuse macros like that.

Comment: I think its the star on the T in your typedef (in UArray2.h). That would make your variable a pointer and in that case you need to access it with uarray->i instead. But as stated above don't abuse macros. It will just confuse you.

Answer (score 4):

In the header file you have

```
typedef struct T *T;
```

This means that when you declare the variable `uarray` you are actually declaring a pointer. So you should initialize the `i` member as

```
uarray->i = 0;
```

This will however most likely crash, as the pointer is uninitialized and can point to any location in memory. Either allocate memory for the pointer

```
UArray2_T uarray = malloc(sizeof(*uarray));
```

Or make it point to another structure

```
struct UArray2_T real_uarray;
UArray2_T uarray = &real_uarray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the initialization as you are using the pointer in the header file.

```
    typedef struct T *T;
```

You are actually pointing to the memory location by declaring uarray.
Try to rectify this error.